# Sticky front brake

Tags: honda, brakes, scooter

My front brake lever will not return back and stick to the depressed position even after I release the brake lever.This is happening from past one week after I washed my scoot

Comment: Is the brake mechanism hydraulic or cable driven? How old is the scooter?

Comment: Its a cable driven system.My scooter is around 3 years old

Comment: Sounds like there is excess friction somewhere or alternatively a spring could be broken. The spring can either be in the brake mechanism or in the brake lever. Water can cause rust, which can cause the friction. I don't believe the rust would break a spring in one week. Oh, and water can mess with lubrication.

Comment: Have you tried lubricating the lever and cable?

Comment: Yes I did lubricate the brake lever with grease and cable with used engine oil.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of 3-year old Honda scooter has cable-operated front brakes? I'm just asking to check that you didn't make a mistake in your answer. Many bodied scooters have concealed master cylinders, and you might not be aware that it is in fact hydraulic if you don't see past the lever. In any case, most modern bikes have disc brakes up front, and most disc brakes are hydraulic by far (the Lambretta SX200, TV175, and DL200 were the first 2-wheelers to have factory front disc brakes, and they were cable-operated, but that was back in the sixties :)). 
If you do have hydraulic disc brakes, the usual culprit is the pistons scoring, rusting, or just drying out. You'll need to clean them, and lubricate them with proper brake-liquid compatible lubricant. WD-40 or oils won't do, as the seals are a special compound.